# Cardview has extra margin when adding elevation

Tags: android, margin, padding, android-cardview, androiddesignsupport

I noticed my cardviews have extra elevation on every side to draw the shadow. I read adding `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` and `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` but I can still see some margin (like 2dp, or padding).

My card:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" />
```

**EDIT:**
As I found out, this issue is caused by using `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`. The problem is, setting card background using `res-auto` works fine, but setting it by using `tools` doesn't work. On the other hand setting `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding` works with `tools` but not with `res-auto`.
If anyone knows why this is happening please let me know.

**EDIT2**
As it turns out, the emulator v23 draws both cards the same, but doesn't apply the background when using `tools`, thus taking `res-auto` seems to be the right choice. So this only seems to be a samsung issue.

Comment: did you noticed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995236/cardview-inside-recyclerview-has-extra-margins

Comment: I already figured out a way to fix it, I just want to know why it does that

Comment: This worked for me:
https://android.jlelse.eu/using-full-width-cards-to-maximize-content-f739cb863ce8