# how i can delete extras margin in CardView inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

How can I delete this extras margin, I trying with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995236/cardview-inside-recyclerview-has-extra-margins) answers but not work.

[image]

My code CardView

```
< LinearLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: card_view = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >

 < android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android: id = "@+id/cartaExposicion"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "300dp"
card_view: cardPreventCornerOverlap = "false" >

 < ImageView
android: id = "@+id/imgExposicion"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "300dp"
android: src = "@mipmap/makuma_0salas" / >
 < /android.support.v7.widget.CardView> < /LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I need delete the spacing into cardview

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which extra margin do you mean? Do you mean the spacing that you have between the CardViews?

Comment: yes @Knossos it's correct  the spacing  between the CardViews

Comment: @Knossos sorry, the spacing it's into cardview,how i can delete this spacing?

Comment: It looks like you are setting 300dp for the `ImageView` and `CardView`, but the image that fills it isn't actually 300dp in height. So it does not fill that view. Try setting both `ImageView` and `CardView` to wrap_content for height. Alternatively try setting `ImageView` `scaleType` to `fit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, the size the images it's very big, i use image small and work fine.

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try giving negative values for card view content padding

```
card_view:contentPadding="-5dp"
```

If you want to remove padding unevenly. Try giving different values for contentPaddingLeft, contentPaddingRight,contentPaddingBottom and contentPaddingTop.

Hope this will work for you.