# Android CardView inside RecyclerView - cardElevation cause unwanted margin & bottom shadow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-elevation

In Android, I am using `RecyclerView`. For RecyclerView's item, I am using CardView as item's layout, with below xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    .......

    </LinearLayout>
</CardView>
```

I am using CardView from `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`.

I set `cardElevation="2dp", layout_marginBottom="0dp", layout_marginTop="0dp"`. Setting cardElevation makes shadow around left, right & bottom of CardView. Then by setting layout_marginBottom & layout_marginTop=0dp, if item is not the last item in the list, it's bottom shadow will `disappear` as it is covered by the next item (CardView) in the list.

Below is the intended UI behaviour. Whole Watchlist looks like single CardView, but indeed it is a RecyclerView, with each item consists of CardView, just the bottom shadow is covered up by next item below it. This works well in Android API 25 (Android 7.1.2) :

[image: Correct Behaviour - Api 25]

But on Android API 16 (Android 4.1.2), outcome is not as expected. The bottom shadow (border) still is visible, also look like there is extra margin added between each item.

[image: Wrong Behaviour - Api 16]

Any idea how to solve this problem in Android 4.1.2 ?

Comment: `Elevation` attribute is only applicable in Android API over 21. <br>Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445593/5402482) link for getting an idea for implementing the desired effect below API 21 :

Comment: The OP is not asking why `Elevation` is not working. (She is using `app:cardElevation` from support library. So, it make sense to see elevation effect in Android 4) She is asking why there is *no* space between rows in Android 6, but there's space between rows in Android 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My raw guess is, you are using `CardView` from support library. There are different card view implementation under different version of of Android.

I believe before Android L, the library add padding in order to reserve space for shadow drawing.

Please check [CardView inside RecyclerView has extra margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995236/cardview-inside-recyclerview-has-extra-margins) for more details.